# Identifying cabinet hinge

Tags: cabinets

[image: Cabinet hinge]

I'm renting this house and one of these hinges broke.

1.) Can I replace this hinge?

2.) If so, what's the model number/manufacturer?

Comment: If one broke and you happen to find a suitable replacement you may want to pickup a spare in case another one breaks. It is my experience that many of this type of hinge are not made with an eye to an enduring ruggedness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Yes, it can be replaced with any hinge that has the same offset and radius even if it doesn't match the exact visual design.

2) It looks like this one:  [Full Overlay Soft Close Clip On Cabinet Cup Hinge HG1019](http://www.keystoneaccents.com/products/Full-Overlay-Soft-Close-Clip-On-Cabinet-Cup-Hinge-HG1019.html)

Comment: +1 And you may want to buy a pair. That way, even if it is not an exact match, you can replace both hinges on the door to ensure parallel function.